# Build a statistical model based on small sample size

Tags: machine-learning, sample-size, model, small-sample, chemometrics

I hope my question is not too wide and that this is the right place to ask it.
I'm working in the field of spectroscopy and chemometrics. I'm building a statistical model to predict pollution levels in soil samples based on the spectrum of the samples (400-2500 nm region). The model is build based on 14 samples which I have created in the lab containing increasing amounts of pollution (crude oil). Then, I used this model to predict the pollution level of 20 samples of soil taken from the research area and I got good results.

My question is regarding the sample size. Since I have only 14 samples, is there an inherent statistical problem with building a model based on a small sample size even though I get good predictions outcome? in other words, if I ought to send my research to a peer-review journal, what kind of review I should expect to receive? or maybe there is nothing wrong with building a model which is based on a small sample size?

Comment: Small sample sizes are not necessarily a problem, it depends on your data and the population. Usually you would do a power analysis to show that while you sample size is small, the power of your test is high, so you have high confidence in your results.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example of power analysis?

Comment: The power analysis method depends on your model, so if you want more information you will need to provide specific information about your model and your data. Otherwise type power analysis "your model type" here or on your search engine of choice and you will get the relevant links.

Comment: I compared different models results, but my main ones are multiple linear regression and PLSR (partial least square regression)

Comment: There already exist functions that perform power analysis for a linear model so that you do not have to code it yourself, have a look at https://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html

Comment: Welcome to cross validated. Yes, this question is right here, and yes there are a (very) few people from analytical chemistry/spectroscopy/chemometrics here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong in *building* a model on small sample size: there exist "easy" questions that don't need many samples to arrive at a sufficiently performant model.
That is, we do have tools that allow us to restrict our models in order to cope with very small sample sizes from a mathematical and numerical point of view. And also from an analytical-chemical point of view it is perfectly fine to very much restrict your calibration range to a particular contaminant and matrix (soil) as long as you are a) aware that your method cannot be used outside these very specific conditions and b) you can show that they are well adapted to the "field question".

The point to keep in mind is that nevertheless, your 14 samples carry only so much information, and are representative only for the matrix/contaminant conditions you chose to cover. So: is that information sufficient to answer your research question? Are your lab soils and contaminants sufficiently similar to your real samples? Do the lab samples cover the range of conditions encountered with the real samples? Particularly the 2nd and 3rd question are crucial, but only indirectly related to sample size.

This is asked (and answered) during verification and validation of your analytical method.
Roughly speaking, **verification** means proving that your method returns the correct analysis results. (I.e. what you do by comparing your method's predictions with reference analyses) **Valdiation** takes a broader view and steps back to ask whether the analysis results are actually answering the right question e.g.: is your chosen calibration range appropriate not only in terms of concentration but also in terms of contaminants and matrix/soil type. 
(Caveat: many people use "validation" for what is actually a verification, e.g. "internal validation" and "cross validation" are actually verification rather than validation, even "external validation" is often set up in a way that it can anser verification questions only).

---

- another point of field-specific terminology. In chemometrics and analytical chemistry, we typically talk more about sensitivity and cross-sensitivities of a method than about power analysis.
- Have a look into model diagnostics for your models. Internal verification techniques can be used to check about underfitting or overfitting of your model. Btw: it can show signs of both if the training sample size is too small.
- Crucial point: uncertainty on your internal verification (figures of merit) depends on the *absolute* number of tested cases. In contrast to training, there's no way totry to cope with small sample size in verification. Thus, it is quite possible that verification rather than training (if that is done properly) is the bottleneck where your small sample size hurts.
  I.e., **a perfect model doesn't help if you cannot prove that is as good as you claim**.
- Franco Allegrini and Alejandro Olivieri have been doing a lot of work on how to extend the typical univariate figures of merit for analytical performance and prediction intervals to multivariate models (their approach does crucially need full independence between your samples/data rows, though).  Also, if you read German, there has been some interesting work back in the 80s looking into similar questions.

Comment: Thanks, so from what I understood, there is no inherited problem with a small sample size to train a model. I only need to be aware of the limitations of such a model.

Comment: @user88484 yes :-)